# save and read a file on disk

Tags: java

I have a matrix with double elements that is produced in my application, I want to save it on disk and in another application read it and access each elements in matrix. How Can I do this?

Comment: -1 For lack of research effort

Answer (score 3):

If it's an array of doubles, [serialisation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) looks like a relatively trivial solution, since both Java arrays and doubles are serialisable by default. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467193/java-serialization-of-multidimensional-array) for more details.