# How do I add numbers in a text file array to a 2d int array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I made a 2d array chart that shows and calculates the average noise levels of each car model as my school project. Now I need to have a separate file to store my array values and put them in the chart.  I've tried to add the values in using a while loop but it gives me this error. How can I add values from my text file to the array? I am still new to java.

```
public static void writetoarray(){
 try{
    k = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));

 }
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("You got an error");
}
 int i = 0;
 while(k.hasNextInt()){
    firstarray[0][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[1][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[2][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[3][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[4][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[5][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[6][i] = k.nextInt();
    i++;
    }
  }


"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at practice.writetoarray(practice.java:29)
 at practice.main(practice.java:11)"
```

This is my whole code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
public class practice {
public static Scanner k;
public int foo = Integer.parseInt(k.next());    
public static int n = 1;
public static int firstarray[][] ={{81,90,92,103,111,121,132,0},
{78,85,90,99,104,111,118,0},{80,86,91,95,100,108,119,0},
{87,90,95,101,111,121,133,0},{66,70,76,86,96,115,125,0},
{81,83,85,93,102,113,122,0},{76,78,80,85,94,104,114,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
public static int y = 0;    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String tableheadings[][]={{"\t\t\t\t    MPH"+"                              
|"},{"Model|","20","30","40","50","60","70","80","Avg     |",},
{"_____________________________________
___________________________________|"}};


writetoarray();
displayheader(tableheadings);
countArraytotal(firstarray);
arrayavg(firstarray);
arrayavgc(firstarray);
printrows(firstarray);
countRowandCol(firstarray);
}


 public static void writetoarray(){
 try{
    k = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));

 }
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("You got an error");
}
 int i = 0;
 while(k.hasNextInt()){
    firstarray[0][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[1][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[2][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[3][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[4][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[5][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[6][i] = k.nextInt();
    i++;
   }

 }



 public static void displayheader(String a[][]){
    for (int row=0 ;row<a.length;row++){
        for(int column=0; column<a[row].length;column++){
        System.out.print(a[row][column]+"\t");
        }
    System.out.println();
}
}

public static void printrows(int a[][]){

for (int row=0 ;row<a.length;row++){
    if(row<a.length-1){
    System.out.print(n+++"    |\t");
    }
    else{System.out.print("Avg  |\t");}
    for(int column=0; column<a[row].length;column++){

        System.out.print(a[row][column]+"\t");

    }

    System.out.print("|");
    System.out.println();
 }
}

public static void arrayavg(int[][] array) {
int s=   0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ s=0;
for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){             
s += array[i][j];
}
firstarray[i][7] = Math.round(s/(array.length-1));  
 }
}

public static void arrayavgc(int[][] array) {
int s=   0;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ s=0;
for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){             
s += array[j][i];
}
firstarray[7][i] = Math.round(s/(array[i].length-1));
}
}

public static void countArraytotal(int[][] table){
int total=0;

for (int row=0;row<table.length;row++)
for (int col=0;col<table[0].length;col++)
  total += table[row][col];
firstarray[7][7]=Math.round(total/49);
}

public static void countRowandCol(int[][] array){
int rowsize = array.length;
int columnSize = array.length;
System.out.println("There are " + rowsize + " rows and " + columnSize+ " 
columns in this table.");

}
}
```

Also, ignore the values I already have in my array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java serialization of multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467193/java-serialization-of-multidimensional-array)

Comment: What is the text in the `test.txt` Share the file.

Comment: It looks like the value in the file is more than the size of the array i.e why you are getting `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Other possible duplicate: [What is a NullPointerException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: in the test.txt is just a couple numbers to test the program:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

Comment: I've solved the NullPointer exception but k.nextInt() is still giving me an error.

      `Exception in thread "main"  java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at practice.writetoarray(practice.java:42)
 at practice.main(practice.java:12)`

Answer (score 0):

One problem I notice is here:

```
try{
    k = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
 }
catch(Exception e){
    // You really should print out the full exception details here
    // It'll make debugging much easier
    System.out.println("You got an error");
}

// If you keep going after an exception here, you'll get a NullPointerException
// because k isn't initialized validly
int i = 0;
while(k.hasNextInt()){
    firstarray[0][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[1][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[2][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[3][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[4][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[5][i] = k.nextInt();
    firstarray[6][i] = k.nextInt();
    i++;
}
```

If there's an exception when you try to initialize `k`, then you can't use it because it won't actually have been created.

Also, rather than printing out "You got an error" in the case when there's an exception, I strongly suggest printing out the full exception details (`e.toString()` will print out the exception message and stack trace). Obviously, you wouldn't want to display that to users in an actual production system, but for learning purposes it makes debugging a lot easier if you display (or at least log) the full details. (In production systems, we usually create a log of some kind with the full details of an exception like this so that we can debug more easily).